# Tags [like] vs. [facebook-like]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I draw your attention to the tags [like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/like) and [facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like).

Only [like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/like) has a tag wiki, which currently reads:

> A way to give positive feedback or to connect with things you care about on Facebook.

So, they're obviously synonyms of each other.

[like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/like) by itself is awfully generic. I suspect that it was created when someone tagged their question [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/like) instead of [facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like). (An easy mistake to make.)

I don't have a particular suggestion as to how this should be handled except that it should be handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, I agree - barring from an odd question most [like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/like) questions were all about [facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like). The tagging system supports synonyms, so I've merged the two tags and created a synonym.

```
updating post history, 31 rows affected
updating posts, 22 rows affected
updating PostTags associations, 20 rows affected
removing/renaming old tag, 0 rows affected
updating count for master tag, 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [facebook-like] and [like] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
0 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
Tag Synonym like -> facebook-like was approved!
Broadcasting tag-engine reload
```