# What to do with [*search*]? Review of tag naming practices in Web Applications SE for tags using "search"

Tags: discussion, tags

## TL;DR

"search" doesn't mean the same for all. Who are the experts answering questions in Web Applications SE and what could we do be make the Web Applications tags better serve them? More specifically what should we do with [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) and the tags having the `search` string on their name?

### Options

1. *Burninate* [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search).
   Burninate is the removal of a tag of all the questions having it. It does not always include blocking a tag to prevent it from reappearing. Blocking a tag is reserved for tags causing harm repeatedly.
2. Improve the tag wiki
3. Rename
4. Retag

The actions might be combined.

### What is expected

Mainly focus on discussing what to do with [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) considering convenience or not having, i.e., [gmail-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-search) Vs. [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) + [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search).

We have [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) and [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) and [yahoo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo) and [yahoo-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-search). The [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) and [yahoo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo) are for questions that are not specific to a single product or on questions when there is not yet a specfic tag for the related product, and [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) and [yahoo-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-search) are for questions about the web search engine of the respective companies named after a product or portal. In these cases, it might be better to consider using [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine) instead of [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search).

---

## Addendum

### Participation in Web Applications SE is low.

Many users who frequently answered questions in Web Applications SE have not been active in a long time.

| User | Answers | Last Seen Active | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ale](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/354/ale) | 1,415 | Jul 15, 2020 at 0:42 | [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) All Time Top Answerer by score |
| [pnuts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/60716/pnuts) | 837 | Feb 7, 2020 at 22:43 |  |
| [phwd](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/40/phwd) | 646 | Feb 21, 2022 at 12:24 | [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) All Time Top Answerer by number of answers |
| [eith days of malayse](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/410/eight-days-of-malaise) | 220 | Apr 12, 2018 at 17:47 |  |

Some others have been active recently; their last answer was posted over a year ago.

While we haven't had many questions by day on average for the last two weeks, there are questions bumped by Community user (bot) every hour. Many of these questions don't have an answer, and many have an answer that has not voted, which might be because they are not good answers to be accepted or upvoted.

Recently, some of those questions bumped by Community user have tags with the `search` string.

### Tags with the `search` string

Searching [*search*] is expanded into

[google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) or [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) or [gmail-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-search) or [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine) or [google-image-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-image-search) or [google-drive-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-search) or [facebook-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-search) or [search-operators](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-operators) or [twitter-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-search) or [google-custom-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search) or [google-search-history](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search-history) or [facebook-graph-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-search) or [google-safesearch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-safesearch) or [researchgate](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/researchgate) or [yandex-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yandex-search) or [yahoo-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-search) or [google-search-console](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console)

The numbers in parenthesis after each tag name are the number of questions.

| Concept (Meta tag?) | Web Apps | Product Built-in Search Feature | Related Features | Related Concepts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **search** (338) | google-search (796) google-image-search <sup>1</sup> (62) google-custom-search<sup>1</sup> (13) google-search-console (2) facebook-graph-search (9) researchgate (3) yahoo-search (2) yandex-search (3) | gmail-search (124) twitter-search (16) google-drive-search (25) facebook-search (18) | google-search-history (11) google-safesearch (6) | search-engine (84) search-operators (18) |

### Is [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) a meta tag in Web Applications SE?

In Web Applications [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) can't be the only tag in a question; however, it could be argued that it means the same for certain audiences. The question is if that audience is still active on Web Applications in 2023 and in the coming years, and most important is if [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) will help connect questions with experts who can answer questions having this tag.

Few [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search)'s Top Users answered more than ten questions. No users score 100, and 20 answers the thresholds to earn the tag bronze badge.

In the early days of the tag wikis, people created them with content resembling a dictionary or Wikipedia.
At this time, this tag only has the tag excerpt.

> Ways and methods to look up data and information from a service, index or some other collection of information

If we keep this tag, we should ensure that this tag wiki has a tag wiki providing proper usage guidance for Web Application SE questions, giving usage guidance to new users and curators. Once this is decided, all questions might need to be reviewed but especially migrated questions, as the tag usage might not be the same on other sites.

As of October 22, 2023, [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) has 338 questions and 505 answers. There are 299 open questions.

#### Does it make sense to use brand-search instead of brand + search

| Company / Portal | Tag for Search Engine Product |
| --- | --- |
| [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google) | [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) |
| [yahoo](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo) | [yahoo-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yahoo-search) |
| [yandex] | [yandex-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yandex-search) |

#### Does it make sense to use [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) in questions about using a web app built-in search feature?

#### Does it make sense to use [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) in questions about search engines?

Having [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) and any other search engine tags including [search-engine](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search-engine) together with [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) looks redundant.

#### Does it make sense to use [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) in questions about search formulas?

There are 17 questions [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) together with [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) and 8 questions tagged [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) and [formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula).

### (1) Google being Google

Since 2009, the year of the oldest question on Web Applications SE (it was migrated from Stack Overflow to Super User and then to Web Applications SE), Google has renamed many of its products. Among them, several of the tags mentioned above <sup>1</sup> correspond to products that have been renamed.

Note: As of October 22, 2023 [created:2009 is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A2009%20is%3Aq) returns 34 questions.

| Tag | Remark | Link |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [google-image-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-image-search) | Google Images is now part of Google Search | [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5154/88163) |
| [google-custom-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search) | Google Custom Search is now Google Programmable Search Engine | [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5156/88163) |

### (2) Search feature of Web applications

Meta Stack Exchange, there are discussions about tag naming. There is no consensus about the vocabulary for tag naming, but there is a consensus that tags should not be named by creating terms by combining two or more existing terms. According to this, transposing this to Web applications and, more specifically, to the tags related to most product feature tags listed above instead of having a tag product-name + product-feature, it's "recommended" to use two tags, one for the product-name and another for the feature.

The only tag in the **Product Built-in Search Feature** column that is not an app content search feature is [google-safesearch](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-safesearch). In this case, `search` is used in the tag name because the feature name is [SafeSearch](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/510?hl=en). Simply put, it filters search results that are not considered safe according to Google criteria refined with users' feedback.

Each case might need to have its post. Below will be listed each

| Tag | Tentative retag | Remarks | Link |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [facebook-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-search) | [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) |  | [A task for the task jar: Clean up facebook questions and tags as they are bumpep by Community user](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5152/) |
| [gmail-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-search) | [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) | Gmail search is strongly related to Gmail filters. Related tag [gmail-filters](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail-filters) |  |
| [google-drive-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive-search) | [google-drive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-drive) [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) |  |  |
| [twitter-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter-search) | [twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter)[search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) | Twitter was recently rebranded to X but people still calls it Twitter |  |

### (3) Web apps that are better suited for other sites

[google-search-console](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console) is like [google-analytics](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics). Both are tags about web applications better suited for [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

### Other related tags

- [filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/filter)
- [formula](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formula)
- [keyword](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/keyword)
- [privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy)

## Related

- [Please don't double tag Google items](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/540/88163)
- [Tags [like] vs. [facebook-like]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2306/88163)
- [Let's clean up some meta tags](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2696/88163)
- [In the context of Web Applications, which are the tags that are not specific to a web application that are not meta-tags?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3986/88163)
- [When [facebook-games], when [facebook][facebook-games], when [facebook] [games], or what?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4372/88163)

### Example posts related to Google product names

- [Make [gmail-chat] synonymous of [google-talk]](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3786/88163)
- [Can we rename [google-spreadsheets] and [google-spreadsheets-query]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4351/88163)
- [Can the name of the [google-team-drive] tag be changed to [google-shared-drive]?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4709/88163)
- [Google Apps is now "G Suite"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4072/88163)
- [What to do with Google Chat?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4740/88163)

Answer (score 0):

[google-image-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-image-search)

The tag wiki doesn't include a tag usage guidance. It barely mentions what "google-image-search" is and a very basic description of how it works, which is obsolete.

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Images) requires an update. While Web Search and Images have their homepages

- https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en for Web Search
- https://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en for Images

The results pages show an integrated look and feel, as they share the same header and use the same URL: https://www.google.com/search.

The tab for Web Search uses **All** as the title. There isn't a "text only" or similar. "All" might show knowledge panels based on the search query, including a knowledge panel specific to images. Knowledge panels of other knowledge types might show images.

The search box now includes two buttons, one to use audio recording as input and the other to use an image as input. When using an image as input, use **lens** as hostname. The domain is still **google.com**. The resulting base URL is `https://lens.google.com`.

Notes:

This "merge" has not been done to services like Google Books, Google Finance, Google Maps, Google Scholar, Google Video.

Answer (score 0):

[google-custom-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-custom-search)

The corresponding web application has changed its name and had several changes. The current name is Programmable Search Engine. While the old URL, [www.google.com/cse](http://www.google.com/cse) is redirected to the new URL, the Programmable Search Engine is similar to Google Search Console and Google Analytics in that it's a better fit for [Webmasters SE](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

The newest question posted on Web Applications was posted in 2016.

Ref. [Custom Search Engine is now Programmable Search Engine](https://programmablesearchengine.googleblog.com/2020/04/custom-search-engine-is-now_30.html).