# Google-Fu recent changes

Tags: discussion, chat

Today, looking at [Google-Fu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7/google-fu) chatroom info, I noticed that our newest elected moderator was not a chatroom owner, so I added him.

Sorry, Blind Spots, for the delay.

This led me to think about the convenience of updating the chatroom description and tags. Suggestions?

##### Top Tags

Since the Tags page shows all-time popularity and some of these tags have not been active recently, I think adding the Top Tags using a SEDE query could be a good idea.

I did a quick search, and one of the results that attracted my attention was [Top Tags in the last Month](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/88618/top-tags-last-month). The result is

| Tag | Count | Remarks (Mine) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) | 37 |  |
| [formulas](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/formulas) | 13 | It's not a web app. |
| [google-chrome](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome) | 10 | It's not a web app. |
| [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) | 8 |  |
| [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) | 7 |  |
| [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) | 5 |  |
| [google-sheets-dates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets-dates) | 5 | It's not a web app. |
| [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) | 5 |  |
| [google-apps-script](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) | 4 |  |
| [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/search) | 4 | It's not a web app. See Related section. |

Putting aside the tags not corresponding to a specific web app, I think the following might be appropriate to be added to the chatroom.

[google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets),[google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search),[facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook),[gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail),[google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs)

Related

- [What to do with [*search*]? Review of tag naming practices in Web Applications SE for tags using "search"](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5144/88163)

---

##### Questions and Answers from Top Tags in the Last Month

SEDE queries work with updated on Sundays. https://data.stackexchange.com/help tells when the last updated occurred. I mention this because if you do a search now, you might get different counts.

| Tag | Search | Questions | Answers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| All | [created:32d...3d is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=created%3A32d...3d%20is%3Aq) | 126 | 151 |
| [google-sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-sheets) | [[google-sheets] created:32d...3d is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bgoogle-sheets%5D%20created%3A32d...3d%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3) | 39 | 60 |
| [google-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-search) | [[google-search] created:32d...3d is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-search%5D%20created%3A32d...3d%20is%3Aq) | 8 | 19 |
| [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) | [[facebook] created:32d...3d is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bfacebook%5D%20created%3A32d...3d%20is%3Aq&searchOn=3) | 7 | 1 |
| [gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gmail) | [[gmail] created:32d...3d is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgmail%5D%20created%3A32d...3d%20is%3Aq) | 6 | 6 |
| [google-docs](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-docs) | [[google-docs] created:32d...3d is:q](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-docs%5D%20created%3A32d...3d%20is%3Aa) | 5 | 8 |

---

I removed [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) from the Google-Fu chatroom description because while there are new questions, there was only one answer in the last month.

I'm wondering if it might be possible to add [featured](/questions/tagged/featured). It is not shown in the autocomplete list.

[Martin at Google-Fu](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64633470#64633470)

> It seems that this feature request is asking exactly for this: [Can we have meta tags for chatrooms](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242307)?