# A task for the task jar: Clean up facebook questions and tags as they are bumped by Community user

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, meta-tags

This is about the intersection of several concerns and because it's related to one of my ignored tags. I will not be ignoring it *so much*, anymore.

1. Hourly bumps by Community user of neglected posts (question with no votes, questions having answers with no votes) having bumped too many times (>10).
2. Many [facebook*] tags look like arbitrary combinations and might hinder the use of [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) when it's really needed.
3. The lack of active [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) experts helping to answer and moderate  [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) questions.
4. Review of [*search*], more specifically of [facebook-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-search)

So my "plan" is when a new question appears on the Homepage

1. Look if it was bumped by Community user; in such case look at the question timeline to find out how many times it was bumped and add a comment about that.
2. Review the question tags.

I put *plan* between quotes because there is no due date or specific time assigned to work on this. Consider this as a piece of paper in a *task jar*.

If someone is interested in joining, please add a comment.

Below, I added some data. Later, I might add more details and updates. If something might require a longer space, I will post an answer or a new question.

---

[facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) has 3,134 questions. Searching for [facebook*], the page results say that there are 3,423 questions. 289 questions have a tag starting with `facebook` but not the tag [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook).

The search query is extended to

Tagged with [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) or [facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages) or [facebook-messenger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger) or [facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) or [facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline) or [facebook-privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-privacy) or [facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) or [facebook-events](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-events) or [facebook-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-photos) or [facebook-notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-notifications) or [facebook-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-apps) or [facebook-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tags) or [facebook-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-account) or [facebook-profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-profile) or [facebook-comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-comments) or [facebook-ads](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-ads) or [facebook-friend-request](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-friend-request) or [facebook-integration](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-integration) or [facebook-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-search) or [facebook-lookback](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-lookback)

The results page for [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) show the following related tags ([instagram](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram) and [meta-business-suite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-business-suite) were not included on the related tags, but they are related).

| Facebook feature? | Facebook's (Company) app? | related apps? generic tags? meta tags? | Third-party apps? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages) × 406 | [facebook-messenger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger) × 198 | [privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/privacy) × 135 |  |
| [facebook-groups](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-groups) × 170 | [instagram](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instagram) | [friends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friends) × 59 -> [facebook-friends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-friends) |  |
| [facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline) × 135 | [meta-business-suite](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-business-suite) | [friend-list](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friend-list) × 29 |  |
| [facebook-privacy](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-privacy) × 129 |  | [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery) × 28 |  |
| [facebook-like](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-like) × 72 |  | [notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/notifications) × 58 |  |
| [facebook-photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-photos) × 69 |  |  | [twitter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/twitter) × 57 |
| [facebook-events](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-events) × 64 |  | [security](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) × 53 |  |
| [facebook-notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-notifications) × 59 |  | [photos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/photos) × 44 |  |
| [facebook-tags](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tags) × 47 |  | [comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) × 36 |  |
| [facebook-apps](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-apps) × 39 |  | [login](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login) × 32 |  |
| [facebook-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-account) × 34 |  | [account-management](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-management) × 45 |  |
| [facebook-profile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-profile) × 29 |  | [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) × 29 |  |

Tags from the Tags page

| Facebook feature? | Facebook's (Company) app? |
| --- | --- |
| [facebook-videos](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-videos) 11 questions | [facebook-graph-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-search) 9 questions |
| [facebook-games](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-games) 10 questions | [facebook-developers](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-developers) 8 questions |
| [facebook-friends](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-friends) 10 questions |  |
| [facebook-subscriptions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-subscriptions) 9 questions |  |
| [facebook-marketplace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-marketplace) 9 questions |  |
| [facebook-questions](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-questions) 8 questions |  |
| [facebook-business-manager](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-business-manager) 7 questions |  |
| [facebook-archive](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-archive) 6 questions |  |
| [facebook-username](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-username) 3 questions |  |
| [facebook-insights](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-insights) 2 questions |  |
| [facebook-live-video](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-live-video) 2 questions |  |
| [facebook-abuse-reporting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-abuse-reporting) 2 questions |  |
| [facebook-chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-chat) 0 questions |  |
| [facebook-tagging](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-tagging) 0 questions |  |

Answer (score 1):

[facebook-graph-search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-graph-search)

This tag is about a feature of Facebook Search. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Graph_Search), Facebook Graph Search was deprecated in June 2019.

As of October 31, 2023, there are five questions open. Eventually, they should be closed because of what was said above. Before closing these five questions it should be reviewed that they are properly tagged.

Answer (score 0):

[facebook-timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline)

There are 21 questions including this tag but not including [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook): [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-timeline+-facebook).

Answer (score 0):

[facebook-pages](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages)

There are 107 questions including this tag but not including [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook) [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-pages+-facebook)

Answer (score 0):

[facebook-messenger](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger)

There are 55 questions including this tag but not including [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook): [search](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-messenger+-facebook).

The question bumped a few moments ago looks to me like that was "double tagged": It included [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook), but it doesn't about using the Facebook web app. Some might argue that it's relevant due to the overall content, but others might rebuttal with multiple arguments that I will not mention at this time. First, it might be required to get the participation of subject matter experts.

I'm biased due to a "community consensus" about not double tagging questions about Google products with [google](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google). At some time in the future, it might be worth discussing how similar / different the situation is around [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook).